# How to convert a nested JSON file into a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to convert a nested JSON in a dataframe using Python. However, all the solutions applied missed some part of the JSON file. In particular, I tried to use the function "_json_normalize", but this function only partially unlists the JSON file.

[image: Result obtained with function "_json_normalize"]

The following JSON represents a partial input of the file.

```json
[
    {
        "repository": "https://github.com/apache/commons-cli.git",
        "sha1": "34209ca517db46da273c2ee0ca1d8f532b599cbd",
        "url": "https://github.com/apache/commons-cli/commit/34209ca517db46da273c2ee0ca1d8f532b599cbd",
        "refactorings": []
    },
    {
        "repository": "https://github.com/apache/commons-cli.git",
        "sha1": "809bd30902215afdc80d8c911f5051e3e8a2da65",
        "url": "https://github.com/apache/commons-cli/commit/809bd30902215afdc80d8c911f5051e3e8a2da65",
        "refactorings": []
    },
    {
        "repository": "https://github.com/apache/commons-cli.git",
        "sha1": "4cca25d72b216bfc8f2e75e4a99afb608ceb6df8",
        "url": "https://github.com/apache/commons-cli/commit/4cca25d72b216bfc8f2e75e4a99afb608ceb6df8",
        "refactorings": [
            {
                "type": "Inline Variable",
                "description": "Inline Variable chr : Character in method package setOpt(opt Option) : void from class org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLine",
                "leftSideLocations": [
                    {
                        "filePath": "src/java/org/apache/commons/cli/CommandLine.java",
                        "startLine": 221,
                        "endLine": 221,
                        "startColumn": 19,
                        "endColumn": 54,
                        "codeElementType": "VARIABLE_DECLARATION_STATEMENT",
                        "description": "inlined variable declaration",
                        "codeElement": "chr : Character"
                    },
                    {
                        "filePath": "src/java/org/apache/commons/cli/CommandLine.java",
                        "startLine": 222,
                        "endLine": 222,
                        "startColumn": 9,
                        "endColumn": 45,
                        "codeElementType": "EXPRESSION_STATEMENT",
                        "description": "statement with the name of the inlined variable",
                        "codeElement": null
                    },
                    {
                        "filePath": "src/java/org/apache/commons/cli/CommandLine.java",
                        "startLine": 214,
                        "endLine": 224,
                        "startColumn": 5,
                        "endColumn": 6,
                        "codeElementType": "METHOD_DECLARATION",
                        "description": "original method declaration",
                        "codeElement": "package setOpt(opt Option) : void"
                    }
                ],
                "rightSideLocations": [
                    {
                        "filePath": "src/java/org/apache/commons/cli/CommandLine.java",
                        "startLine": 223,
                        "endLine": 223,
                        "startColumn": 9,
                        "endColumn": 54,
                        "codeElementType": "EXPRESSION_STATEMENT",
                        "description": "statement with the initializer of the inlined variable",
                        "codeElement": null
                    },
                    {
                        "filePath": "src/java/org/apache/commons/cli/CommandLine.java",
                        "startLine": 216,
                        "endLine": 225,
                        "startColumn": 5,
                        "endColumn": 6,
                        "codeElementType": "METHOD_DECLARATION",
                        "description": "method declaration with inlined variable",
                        "codeElement": "package setOpt(opt Option) : void"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I write the following snippet:

```py
import json

import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize  # package for flattening json in pandas df

# load json object
with open("output/common_cli.json") as f:
    d = json.load(f)

metadata = ["refactorings"]
nycphil = json_normalize(data=d["commits"], meta=metadata, errors="ignore")
x = nycphil.head(3)
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
print(df)
df.to_csv("output/test4.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

With the json file you provided, here is one way to do it by defining a [recursive](https://realpython.com/python-thinking-recursively/) helper function:

```py
def func(data, new_data):
    """Recursive helper function.

    Args:
        data: nested dictionary.
        new_data: empty dictionary.

    Returns:
        Flattened dictionary.

    """
    for key, value in data.items():
        if isinstance(value, list):
            for item in value:
                func(item, new_data)
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            func(value, new_data)
        if isinstance(value, str) or isinstance(value, int):
            new_data[key] = value
    return new_data
```

Then, using Pandas [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) and [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```py
import json
import pandas as pd


# Import json file
with open("file.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
df = pd.json_normalize(data)

# Cleanup
df["refactorings"] = df["refactorings"].apply(lambda x: x[0] if x else {})

# Flatten the column
df["refactorings"] = df.apply(lambda x: func(x["refactorings"], {}), axis=1)


# For each row, flatten nested dict, make a dataframe of it
# and concat it with non nested columns
# Then, concat all new dataframes
new_df = pd.concat(
    [
        pd.concat(
            [
                pd.DataFrame(df.loc[idx, :]).T.drop(columns="refactorings"),
                pd.DataFrame(df.loc[idx, "refactorings"], index=[idx]),
            ],
            axis=1,
        ).fillna(method="ffill")
        for idx in df.index
    ]
).reset_index(drop=True)
```

And so:

```py
print(new_df)
# Output
                                  repository  \
0  https://github.com/apache/commons-cli.git   
1  https://github.com/apache/commons-cli.git   
2  https://github.com/apache/commons-cli.git   

                                       sha1  \
0  34209ca517db46da273c2ee0ca1d8f532b599cbd   
1  809bd30902215afdc80d8c911f5051e3e8a2da65   
2  4cca25d72b216bfc8f2e75e4a99afb608ceb6df8   

                                                                                     url  \
0  https://github.com/apache/commons-cli/commit/34209ca517db46da273c2ee0ca1d8f532b599cbd   
1  https://github.com/apache/commons-cli/commit/809bd30902215afdc80d8c911f5051e3e8a2da65   
2  https://github.com/apache/commons-cli/commit/4cca25d72b216bfc8f2e75e4a99afb608ceb6df8   

              type                               description  ... endLine  \
0              NaN                                       NaN  ...     NaN   
1              NaN                                       NaN  ...     NaN   
2  Inline Variable  method declaration with inlined variable  ...   225.0   

   startColumn  endColumn     codeElementType  \
0          NaN        NaN                 NaN   
1          NaN        NaN                 NaN   
2          5.0        6.0  METHOD_DECLARATION   

                         codeElement  
0                                NaN  
1                                NaN  
2  package setOpt(opt Option) : void
```