# How to convert a complex nested JSON file to CSV in Python?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to convert a complex JSON file to CSV using Python.

```
{
"commits": [
{
    "repository": "https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/",
    "sha1": "1f5edbcd2b5b09ec59151137e643d9ce75ef1055",
    "url": "https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/1f5edbcd2b5b09ec59151137e643d9ce75ef1055",
    "refactorings": [{
    "type": "Add Method Annotation",
    "description": "Add Method Annotation @Override in method public getPreciserScopeKnowingConditionOutcome(condition Node, blindScope FlowScope, outcome boolean) : FlowScope from class com.google.javascript.jscomp.ClosureReverseAbstractInterpreter",
    "leftSideLocations": [{
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ClosureReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 191,
        "endLine": 215,
        "startColumn": 3,
        "endColumn": 4,
        "codeElementType": "METHOD_DECLARATION",
        "description": "original method declaration",
        "codeElement": "public getPreciserScopeKnowingConditionOutcome(condition Node, blindScope FlowScope, outcome boolean) : FlowScope"
}],
    "rightSideLocations": [{
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ClosureReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 200,
        "endLine": 200,
        "startColumn": 3,
        "endColumn": 12,
        "codeElementType": "ANNOTATION",
        "description": "added annotation",
        "codeElement": "@Override"
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ClosureReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 200,
        "endLine": 223,
        "startColumn": 3,
        "endColumn": 4,
        "codeElementType": "METHOD_DECLARATION",
        "description": "method declaration with added annotation",
        "codeElement": "public getPreciserScopeKnowingConditionOutcome(condition Node, blindScope FlowScope, outcome boolean) : FlowScope"
}]
},
{
    "type": "Extract And Move Method",
    "description": "Extract And Move Method private getNativeTypeForTypeOf(value String) : JSType extracted from protected caseTopType(topType JSType) : JSType in class com.google.javascript.jscomp.ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.RestrictByOneTypeOfResultVisitor & moved to class com.google.javascript.jscomp.ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter",
    "leftSideLocations": [{
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 485,
        "endLine": 501,
        "startColumn": 5,
        "endColumn": 6,
        "codeElementType": "METHOD_DECLARATION",
        "description": "source method declaration before extraction",
        "codeElement": "protected caseTopType(topType JSType) : JSType"
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 489,
        "endLine": 489,
        "startColumn": 11,
        "endColumn": 45,
        "codeElementType": "RETURN_STATEMENT",
        "description": "extracted code from source method declaration",
        "codeElement": null
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 491,
        "endLine": 491,
        "startColumn": 11,
        "endColumn": 46,
        "codeElementType": "RETURN_STATEMENT",
        "description": "extracted code from source method declaration",
        "codeElement": null
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 493,
        "endLine": 493,
        "startColumn": 11,
        "endColumn": 45,
        "codeElementType": "RETURN_STATEMENT",
        "description": "extracted code from source method declaration",
        "codeElement": null
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 495,
        "endLine": 495,
        "startColumn": 11,
        "endColumn": 43,
        "codeElementType": "RETURN_STATEMENT",
        "description": "extracted code from source method declaration",
        "codeElement": null
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 497,
        "endLine": 497,
        "startColumn": 11,
        "endColumn": 54,
        "codeElementType": "RETURN_STATEMENT",
        "description": "extracted code from source method declaration",
        "codeElement": null
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 500,
        "endLine": 500,
        "startColumn": 7,
        "endColumn": 22,
        "codeElementType": "RETURN_STATEMENT",
        "description": "extracted code from source method declaration",
        "codeElement": null
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 496,
        "endLine": 498,
        "startColumn": 16,
        "endColumn": 10,
        "codeElementType": "IF_STATEMENT",
        "description": "extracted code from source method declaration",
        "codeElement": null
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 494,
        "endLine": 498,
        "startColumn": 16,
        "endColumn": 10,
        "codeElementType": "IF_STATEMENT",
        "description": "extracted code from source method declaration",
        "codeElement": null
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 492,
        "endLine": 498,
        "startColumn": 16,
        "endColumn": 10,
        "codeElementType": "IF_STATEMENT",
        "description": "extracted code from source method declaration",
        "codeElement": null
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 490,
        "endLine": 498,
        "startColumn": 16,
        "endColumn": 10,
        "codeElementType": "IF_STATEMENT",
        "description": "extracted code from source method declaration",
        "codeElement": null
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 488,
        "endLine": 498,
        "startColumn": 9,
        "endColumn": 10,
        "codeElementType": "IF_STATEMENT",
        "description": "extracted code from source method declaration",
        "codeElement": null
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 494,
        "endLine": 496,
        "startColumn": 47,
        "endColumn": 10,
        "codeElementType": "BLOCK",
        "description": "extracted code from source method declaration",
        "codeElement": null
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 492,
        "endLine": 494,
        "startColumn": 44,
        "endColumn": 10,
        "codeElementType": "BLOCK",
        "description": "extracted code from source method declaration",
        "codeElement": null
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 490,
        "endLine": 492,
        "startColumn": 45,
        "endColumn": 10,
        "codeElementType": "BLOCK",
        "description": "extracted code from source method declaration",
        "codeElement": null
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 488,
        "endLine": 490,
        "startColumn": 37,
        "endColumn": 10,
        "codeElementType": "BLOCK",
        "description": "extracted code from source method declaration",
        "codeElement": null
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 496,
        "endLine": 498,
        "startColumn": 46,
        "endColumn": 10,
        "codeElementType": "BLOCK",
        "description": "extracted code from source method declaration",
        "codeElement": null
}],
    "rightSideLocations": [{
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 595,
        "endLine": 618,
        "startColumn": 3,
        "endColumn": 4,
        "codeElementType": "METHOD_DECLARATION",
        "description": "extracted method declaration",
        "codeElement": "private getNativeTypeForTypeOf(value String) : JSType"
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 606,
        "endLine": 606,
        "startColumn": 7,
        "endColumn": 41,
        "codeElementType": "RETURN_STATEMENT",
        "description": "extracted code to extracted method declaration",
        "codeElement": null
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 608,
        "endLine": 608,
        "startColumn": 7,
        "endColumn": 42,
        "codeElementType": "RETURN_STATEMENT",
        "description": "extracted code to extracted method declaration",
        "codeElement": null
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 610,
        "endLine": 610,
        "startColumn": 7,
        "endColumn": 41,
        "codeElementType": "RETURN_STATEMENT",
        "description": "extracted code to extracted method declaration",
        "codeElement": null
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 612,
        "endLine": 612,
        "startColumn": 7,
        "endColumn": 39,
        "codeElementType": "RETURN_STATEMENT",
        "description": "extracted code to extracted method declaration",
        "codeElement": null
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 614,
        "endLine": 614,
        "startColumn": 7,
        "endColumn": 50,
        "codeElementType": "RETURN_STATEMENT",
        "description": "extracted code to extracted method declaration",
        "codeElement": null
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 616,
        "endLine": 616,
        "startColumn": 7,
        "endColumn": 19,
        "codeElementType": "RETURN_STATEMENT",
        "description": "extracted code to extracted method declaration",
        "codeElement": null
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 613,
        "endLine": 617,
        "startColumn": 12,
        "endColumn": 6,
        "codeElementType": "IF_STATEMENT",
        "description": "extracted code to extracted method declaration",
        "codeElement": null
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 611,
        "endLine": 617,
        "startColumn": 12,
        "endColumn": 6,
        "codeElementType": "IF_STATEMENT",
        "description": "extracted code to extracted method declaration",
        "codeElement": null
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 609,
        "endLine": 617,
        "startColumn": 12,
        "endColumn": 6,
        "codeElementType": "IF_STATEMENT",
        "description": "extracted code to extracted method declaration",
        "codeElement": null
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 607,
        "endLine": 617,
        "startColumn": 12,
        "endColumn": 6,
        "codeElementType": "IF_STATEMENT",
        "description": "extracted code to extracted method declaration",
        "codeElement": null
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 605,
        "endLine": 617,
        "startColumn": 5,
        "endColumn": 6,
        "codeElementType": "IF_STATEMENT",
        "description": "extracted code to extracted method declaration",
        "codeElement": null
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 611,
        "endLine": 613,
        "startColumn": 43,
        "endColumn": 6,
        "codeElementType": "BLOCK",
        "description": "extracted code to extracted method declaration",
        "codeElement": null
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 609,
        "endLine": 611,
        "startColumn": 40,
        "endColumn": 6,
        "codeElementType": "BLOCK",
        "description": "extracted code to extracted method declaration",
        "codeElement": null
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 607,
        "endLine": 609,
        "startColumn": 41,
        "endColumn": 6,
        "codeElementType": "BLOCK",
        "description": "extracted code to extracted method declaration",
        "codeElement": null
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 605,
        "endLine": 607,
        "startColumn": 33,
        "endColumn": 6,
        "codeElementType": "BLOCK",
        "description": "extracted code to extracted method declaration",
        "codeElement": null
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 613,
        "endLine": 615,
        "startColumn": 42,
        "endColumn": 6,
        "codeElementType": "BLOCK",
        "description": "extracted code to extracted method declaration",
        "codeElement": null
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 486,
        "endLine": 496,
        "startColumn": 5,
        "endColumn": 6,
        "codeElementType": "METHOD_DECLARATION",
        "description": "source method declaration after extraction",
        "codeElement": "protected caseTopType(topType JSType) : JSType"
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 490,
        "endLine": 490,
        "startColumn": 29,
        "endColumn": 58,
        "codeElementType": "METHOD_INVOCATION",
        "description": "extracted method invocation",
        "codeElement": "getNativeTypeForTypeOf(value)"
}, {
        "filePath": "src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ChainableReverseAbstractInterpreter.java",
        "startLine": 615,
        "endLine": 617,
        "startColumn": 12,
        "endColumn": 6,
        "codeElementType": "BLOCK",
        "description": "added statement in extracted method declaration",
        "codeElement": null
}]
}
]
}]
}
```

I tried different approaches. However, any of them function perfectly. In particular, I used the solution reported in this post: [How to convert a nested JSON file into a Pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74304278/how-to-convert-a-nested-json-file-into-a-pandas-dataframe)

But this solution partially works only if manually remove the first line (the line commits)

```
{
"commits":
.
.
}
```

However, even removing this line; the generated CSV does not include all the fields, but only a subset. I also tried using the Json_normalize function, but in this case the generated CSV file contained more than one field in a single field.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by partially works?

Comment: it means that the proposed solution works, but only if I manually remove the line 'commits', and also, in this case, the CSV output generated includes only a subset of all the fields indicated in the JSON file.

Comment: i mean the JSON data format is simply differently structured than a .csv file or a dataframe so the more complex your JSON is and the more data you want to keep the harder it is to achieve that

Comment: CSV is a (two-dimensional) table, nothing more. JSON can represent arbitrarily nested data structures, so it can do so much more than CSV. Are you sure you want CSV? In any case, concerning your question, provide a [mcve]. That means extracting a relevant example from both the input data and the transformation code. Include that with the expected and actual output it produces in your question. As a new user here, please also read [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [json_normalize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)

```
left_df = pd.json_normalize(
    data=data["commits"],
    meta=["repository", "sha1", "url", ["refactorings", "type"], ["refactorings", "description"]],
    record_path=["refactorings", "leftSideLocations"]
)
left_df.columns = left_df.columns.str.split(".").str[-1]
left_df.insert(loc=0, column="Location", value="left_side")

right_df = pd.json_normalize(
    data=data["commits"],
    meta=["repository", "sha1", "url", ["refactorings", "type"], ["refactorings", "description"]],
    record_path=["refactorings", "rightSideLocations"]
)
right_df.columns = right_df.columns.str.split(".").str[-1]
right_df.insert(loc=0, column="Location", value="right_side")

pd.concat([left_df, right_df]).reset_index(drop=True).to_csv("/path/to/file/un-nested.csv")
```